# Sum within column based on values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below for the columns `value_to_sum` and `indicator`.  I'd like to sum all values within `value_to_sum` up to and including the most recent value within that column where `indicator == True`.  If `indicator == False`, I do not want to sum.

| row | value_to_sum | indicator | desired_outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | True | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | True | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | False | NaN |
| 4 | 2 | False | NaN |
| 5 | 4 | False | NaN |
| 6 | 6 | True | 10 |
| 7 | 2 | True | 6 |
| 8 | 3 | False | NaN |

How can I achieve the values under `desired_outcome`?

Comment: You wrote: "up to and including the most recent value" but your example  in row 2 shows otherwise. Or did I misunderstood something here? Othweise why is row 6, a 9?

Comment: I don't want to include the value within `value_to_sum` on that same row within the sum under `desired_outcome`.  But the sum should be inclusive of the last row where `indicator == True`.  So "most recent" means the most recent row _previous_ to the row we're at.

Comment: Ok, but then why is row 6 equal 9?

Comment: Good catch!  I summed that one incorrectly!  The sum for row 6 should be the sums of rows 2-5 (3+1+2+4 = 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a group based on the `.cumsum()` of `True` values of column `indicator` and then use `.groupby()` together with `.transform()` to get the sum of `value_to_sum` of each group.

Then, for `indicator` == True, since the desired outcome is up to the previous row, we get the value of `desired_outcome` from last row by using `.shift()`.   At the same time, for `indicator` == False, we set the value of `desired_outcome` to `NaN`.  These last 2 steps are done altogether by a call to `np.where()`.

```
df['desired_outcome'] = df.assign(group=df['indicator'].cumsum()).groupby('group')['value_to_sum'].transform('sum')
df['desired_outcome'] = np.where(df['indicator'], df['desired_outcome'].shift(), np.nan)
```

Result:

```
print(df)



   row  value_to_sum  indicator  desired_outcome
0    1             1       True              NaN
1    2             3       True              1.0
2    3             1      False              NaN
3    4             2      False              NaN
4    5             4      False              NaN
5    6             6       True             10.0
6    7             2       True              6.0
7    8             3      False              NaN
```